# Am I correct about how the basic git commands?

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control

I'm trying to understand git and I was wondering whether you could correct me on any wrong points I make in the following example.

As a simple example, let's say I initialize a repository that consists of the following 2 simple files.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**algorithms.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>   
void reverse_string ( char * s ) 
{
   char * offend = *(s + strlen(s));
   while(offend != s && --offend != s)
   {
      char temp = *s;
      *s = *offend;
      *offend = temp;
      ++s;
   }
}
```

When I make my first `commit` after `add`ing all the files, the content of the 2 files is stored in git and I get back a hash that is computed from the content of the 2 files (plus some metadata such as their location in the directory tree and so forth). This hash is merely an identifier, but can also serve a purpose of checking whether different commits include identical file sets (assuming no collisions in the hashing). Let's say that hash is `firstcommit5njn2n34n`.

Now that I've made a first commit, it's the `base` for all subsequent commits unless I `rebase` at some point.

Let's say I make a slight change to the second file.

**algorithms.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>   
void reverse_string ( char * s ) 
{
   char * offend = *(s + strlen(s));
   while(offend != s && --offend != s)
   {
      char temp = *s;
      *s++ = *offend;
      *offend = temp;
   }
}
```

and make another `commit`. The hash for that `commit` is computed from **algorithms.cpp** only. The file **main.cpp** is not involved in the `commit` at all. (That's I believe it's misleading when people teach git by saying it's a "snapshot of your repository". More accurately, a `commit` is a snapshot of only the files that you changed.) Let's pretend the hash of the commit is `secondcommit5njn2n34n`.

The actual physical repository at this point looks like the original **main.cpp** and the version of **algorithms.cpp** that was in my last `commit`. That last `commit` has an alias called `HEAD`. So, *the way think about how a physical repository at a given point in time is that it is a number of commits applied in order on top of a base commit*.

Let's say I make another change

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      printf("Hello, world!\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

and then `commit`. That 3rd `commit` consists of a snapshot of the above file. Let's pretend its hash is `thirdcommit9123b1nb31n`.

Now my commit history looks like

`firstcommit5njn2n34n`  a.k.a. `base`

----> `secondcommit5njn2n34n`

----> `thirdcommit9123b1nb31n` a.k.a. `HEAD`

Suppose I now run `git checkout secondcommit5njn2n34n`. Under the hood, git runs some logic like

> "Ok, I take those 2 original files he added, main.cpp and
>   algorithms.cpp, then I replace the algorithms.cpp one with the version
>   in the commit secondcommit5njn2n34n."

Now my working directory looks like

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**algorithms.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>   
void reverse_string ( char * s ) 
{
   char * offend = *(s + strlen(s));
   while(offend != s && --offend != s)
   {
      char temp = *s;
      *s = *offend;
      *s++ = *offend;
      *offend = temp;
   }
}
```

The `HEAD` is still `thirdcommit9123b1nb31n`. Is that correct? And what would happen if I changed a file and made another `commit` now? Would that not be allowed or would it make there be two paths in the `commit` history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I make my first commit after adding all the files, the content of the 2 files is stored in git and I get back a hash that is computed from the content of the 2 files (plus some metadata such as their location in the directory tree and so forth). This hash is merely an identifier, but can also serve a purpose of checking whether different commits include identical file sets (assuming no collisions in the hashing). Let's say that hash is `firstcommit5njn2n34n`.

Yes, although it's better to think of this hash as the "true name" of a (or "the", in this case) *commit*.  (In SVN terms it's like the `-r` number.)

> Now that I've made a first commit, it's the base for all subsequent commits unless I rebase at some point.

No: here Git and SVN part ways already.  This first commit is the *current* commit, and to diagram all your commits, you can draw a graph, but right now that graph is quite boring since it has one node (one vertex) with no edges, and one label pointing to the one node:

```
o   <-- master
```

The label is `master`, and it points to (contains the hash ID of) the one commit in the graph.

> ... make another commit. The hash for that commit is computed from **algorithms.cpp** only.

No, this is wrong.

The new hash is the checksum of the new commit.  The *new* commit contains five items: four header items, and the commit message.  Let's take a look at two actual commits, and one tree as well, for concreteness.  I don't have your repository, so here I will use my copy of the repository for Git itself instead.<sup>1</sup>  We can use `git cat-file` to view any object stored in the repository.  With `-p`, it will "pretty print" them in text form (in fact, most are already mostly text, though trees are not; not that this matters for using them).  Here is my current commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /g'
tree 4a87650eeb8ca29bd76be9275a246e35af37904b
parent cf4c2cfe52be5bd973a4838f73a35d3959ce2f43
author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1467720923 -0700
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1467720923 -0700

git diff: improve A...B merge-base handling

When git diff is given a symmetric difference A...B, it chooses
some merge base between the two specified commits.
[snip]
```

Note the `tree` and `parent` lines in particular.  The five items are thus:

1. the tree;
2. the parent;
3. the author;
4. the committer;
5. the commit message.

Compare this to what you see when you look at a "root" (parent-less) commit, such as this one (ID found by `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1`):

```
$ git cat-file -p e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290 | sed 's/@/ /g'
tree 2b5bfdf7798569e0b59b16eb9602d5fa572d6038
author Linus Torvalds <torvalds ppc970.osdl.org> 1112911993 -0700
committer Linus Torvalds <torvalds ppc970.osdl.org> 1112911993 -0700

Initial revision of "git", the information manager from hell
```

Now there are only four items: there is no `parent` line.  (If we look at some merge commits, we will find that they have at least *two* `parent` lines, one per parent commit node.)

The `tree`s in this repository (for Git itself) are quite large, but I can show them (converted from binary to text) with `git cat-file` again.  Here is a snippet:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD:
[snip]
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree 1eb510854c64576991212dc139de0813ff9f2140    Documentation
100755 blob 0fe02a6ce28212200cada0cdce2b19cbc3937cff    GIT-VERSION-GEN
[snip]
```

Let's go back to your repository now since it's much simpler.

> Let's pretend the hash of the commit is `secondcommit5njn2n34n`.

OK.  Meanwhile, the ID for the `tree` line in your *second* commit is computed by:

- hashing the (new) contents of `algorithms.cpp`;<sup>2</sup>
- hashing the (same as before) contents of `main.cpp`;
- writing those hashes, along with the two file names and file-modes (`100644` no doubt), into a "tree" object;
- computing the hash of that tree object.

We can now draw your commit graph as *two* nodes:

```
o <- o   <-- master
```

The name `master` now contains `secondcommit...` which is the right-hand-side `o` node.  That commit contains a `parent` line that contains the ID `firstcommit...`, which thus points to the left-hand side `o` node.  The first commit is a root commit—has no parents; is a dead-end—so the graph stops there, when viewed from the commit level.

When viewed from a lower (tree-and-file/"blob") level, though, each commit has one *tree* object, each of which has two *blob* objects.  To tell commits, trees, and blobs apart, let's label them with letters:

```
o C1  <-  o C2           <-- master
|         |
v         v
o T1      o T2
|\       /|
| \     / |
|  \   /  |
v    v    v
o    o    o
B2   B1   B3
```

I put blob *B1* in the middle here because it's the (unchanged) `main.cpp` file.  That blob has the same hash in both trees, so *both trees point to the same file*.  Blobs *B2* and *B3* here are the two different versions of `algorithms.cpp`.  The two trees *T1* and *T2* are different because *T1* lists *B2* and *B1* under the names `algorithms.cpp` and `main.cpp`, while *T2* lists *B3* and *B1* under those same two names.  The *names* are the same, but the blob hashes differ, so the trees differ.  (And of course the `parent` lines in *C1* and *C2* differ—*C1* has no `parent` lines at all and *C2* has one listing *C1*.  Likewise, the two `tree` lines, the time-stamps, and presumably the commit messages, all differ between the two different commits.)

> The actual physical repository at this point looks like the original **main.cpp** and the version of **algorithms.cpp** that was in my last `commit`.

In fact, it looks instead something like the above "full graph": there are now three blob objects, two tree objects, and two commit objects.  The name `master` contains the ID of the tip commit of a two-commit-long linear chain of commits, with the chain itself being something Git must construct at command-run-time by reading IDs.

> That last commit has an alias called `HEAD`.

Yes, sort of.  In fact, HEAD is an ordinary file (`cat .git/HEAD` to see it), normally containing the *name of a branch*:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/diff-merge-base
```

(in this case I am on branch `diff-merge-base`, which I created to hold my fix to `git diff`).  It's from the reference itself—the branch name—that Git finds the hash ID of the (single) commit.

> So, *the way think about how a physical repository at a given point in time is that it is a number of commits applied in order on top of a base commit.*

This is how many, perhaps even most, other Version Control Systems work.  Mercurial is graph-oriented (so there's no single distinguished "base" version) but otherwise does work much like this.  SVN, CVS, and RCS, which share a lot of developmental history, work much like this except that (at least in CVS and RCS, I have not looked inside SVN) the "trunk" stores reverse-deltas rather than forward-deltas.  SCCS works much like this except that the entire contents of a file (once uniquely identified) are stored as *interleaved* deltas.  (Clearcase uses an object database and I have no idea what its internals are like once you get past the external-name-to-OID mappings.)

Git is very, very different.  It stores a commit graph with trees with names, and its underlying objects are stored purely by content-hash-ID.  The relationships between commits, trees, and files are all computed on the fly every time you run a Git command.  Any delta from one commit to another is also computed on demand.  (Pack files do use a modified form of xdelta compression but objects are compressed against other objects by ID, not files against previous versions of files.<sup>3</sup>)

When you make a new commit, the new commit gets a `tree` (usually from `git write-tree`), zero or more parent commit IDs, an author and committer name-and-date stamp, and a message.  If you (or Git) then write the ID of the new commit to a branch name, the branch now points to the new commit.  It's the new commit's job to point back to any previous commits, to supply any history.  Get the parents right and you will have a sensible commit history.  Pick some arbitrary parent(s) and you will get a bizarre history.

---

<sup>1</sup>Mine is slightly different from the official one as I have a few bug fixes that nobody is taking back.  Maybe posting them to the official mailing list is not the right way to get fixes put into Git?

<sup>2</sup>In fact, the hash is computed earlier, when you `git add` the file.  In general Git computes hashes at the same time it adds an object to the repository database.  This is the best possible time, since the hash is literally the checksum of the contents (including the object's type-and-size header), and Git must scan through these contents in order to write them to a compressed (zlib-deflated) "loose object" file.

Git stores blob hashes in a cache file called (variously) "the index", "the staging-area", or "the cache".  The actual file is `.git/index` and its format is not very well documented.  It amounts to a flattened form of the trees that Git will write for the next commit, except that for every file name, there are up to four "slots", of which at most three are ever used at a time: slot 0 holds the normal file hash, and slots 1-3 hold unmerged files, if a merge stops due to conflicts.

The command `git write-tree` turns the index into one or more `tree` objects and prints out the ID of the top level tree.  This is how the `git commit` command knows what to put in the `tree` line for the new commit.  Note that the index *still has the same flattened trees in it* before and after writing them to a tree object.  Adding a new version of `algorithms.cpp` replaces the old slot-zero entry for `algorithms.cpp`, but does nothing at all to any entries for `main.cpp`.

<sup>3</sup>The delta compression code does use heuristics to choose which objects to compress against each other, and those do use object types, file names extracted from tree objects, and file sizes and various usage patterns, to group objects for compression.  Thus Git winds up often compressing different versions of `algorithms.cpp` against each other.  But *in principle* at least, it could compress blobs against commits and trees.  This is pretty well hidden, except when you see "compressing objects" messages, where Git is re-doing pack compression to speed up network transfers, on the theory that computrons are infinite and free, while networks are a bit slow.

Comment: awesome answer torek. i up voted, buy my only regret is that i have just one +1 to give (credit, nathan hale).

Answer (score 0):

> The HEAD is still thirdcommit9123b1nb31n. Is that correct?

Yes, HEAD always points to the most recent commit on a given branch.

> And what would happen if I changed a file and made another commit now? Would that not be allowed or would it make there be two paths in the commit history?

That's not something that's recommended. When you checkout a specific hash like this you end up in `detached HEAD` mode. You can commit anything you like but those commits are not associated with any branch - so unless you remember the hash you're going to have trouble getting them back.

What you would normally do is `branch` from the commit you're interested in, and switch to that branch:

```
git checkout -b mybranch secondcommit5njn2n34n
```

Now you're on a new branch who's root is at your second commit. You can commit again and you will essentially be running parallel to your original `master` branch. This new branch has it's own HEAD.

Eventually you will probably want to merge those changes back into master, so you can use:

```
git checkout master
git merge mybranch
```

[More info on branching & merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)